# Кто такой хороняка?

Tags: славянизмы, значение-слов

Помните фразу из "Ивана Васильевича": "Ну так и женись, хороняка, князь отпускает ее".
А кто такой, собственно, хороняка и почему Иван Грозный использует это слово как ругательство?
Это как-то связано с похоронами?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Хороняка** -- (др.-рус.) = **трус**

*Полный церковнославянскій словарь прот. Г. Дьяченко*

http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0791.htm

Answer (score 0):

Трусливый человек. Старорусское слово

Comment: Почему Иван Грозный использует это слово как ругательство? (Из вопроса.)